# ReactJS - Display date 1 year prior to current date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, jsx

I'm making a search function with filters for my web app. I have a start date and end date for my queries, but as default I want the end date to always display today's date, but the start date to display the date 1 year prior to whatever 'Today's Date' would be.

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import { Paper } from "@material-ui/core";


class MainSection extends React.Component {
  static contextType = AppContext;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchTerm: "",
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: new Date(),
      update: (data) => {
        console.debug(data)
        this.setState(data);
      },
    };
  }
```

I've currently left startDate blank to avoid confusion.

Expected output would be:

**For Today:**

Start Date: 2019/10/08

End Date: 2020/10/08

**For Tomorrow:**

Start Date: 2019/10/09

End Date: 2020/10/09

Etc...

Worth mentioning that I'm shiny new to programming so If I'm missing something obvious please go easy on me!

Question edit recommendations welcome so I can learn Stack Overflow etiquette.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var date = new Date();
date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 1);
console.log(date)
```

to use it in your code:

```
class MainSection extends React.Component {
  static contextType = AppContext;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const oneYearAgo = new Date();
    oneYearAgo.setFullYear(oneYearAgo.getFullYear() - 1);
    this.state = {
      searchTerm: "",
      startDate: oneYearAgo,
      endDate: new Date(),
      update: (data) => {
        console.debug(data)
        this.setState(data);
      },
    };
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Apologies, but how would i integrate this solution into my code in React?

Comment: please choose as the accepted answer if that worked for you

Comment: Thank you! A lot less complicated than I thought it would be. Can say I've learnt something today!

Answer (score 1):

You can user moment.js library for all the date manipulation requirements. It has substract function which you can use to get date 1 year back.
For React there is react-moment npm which will be handy.

below are links..
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment#add-and-subtract

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this code

```js
var date = new Date();
document.querySelectorAll('#originalDate')[0].innerText = date.toISOString()

date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 1);
document.querySelectorAll('#editedDate')[0].innerText = date.toISOString()
```

```html
<p id="originalDate"> </p>
<p id="editedDate"> </p>
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I apply this into my code in React though? I have my displayed dates converted to ISO on the view pages so that's no issue.